# What is the error denotes in Android(JSON) Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:

Tags: android, json

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:

Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONArray ja= (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(0);
                    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
                    //String firstvalue = jb.getString("0");
                    int secondvalue = jb.getInt("customer_id");
```

Myjson output should like `[[{"0":"2","customer_id":"2"}]]`

i am jenerating the output using the php like

```
$output[]= $customerid;
print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: @Raghunandan i tried your code that says the above error.

Comment: post your question here on SO itself.

Comment: post your entire json here not only the code.

Comment: @Raghunandan look at my code

Comment: this is exactly like the previous question you posted and i have answered there. The answer posted will work if you have the json as above. Is this your complete json?

Comment: yes it is my complete json. i tried your code says that error

Comment: your customer id is string, you need to convert it to int. 
`int secondvalue = Integer.parseInt(jb.getString("customer_id"));`

Also where exactly you are facing the issue?

Comment: @Rajeev logcat doesn't show the exact line it shows only above error

Comment: @user2607115 in your catch block do `e.printStackTrace()`. Also is result a string?

Comment: @user2607115 you can debug sir. It will tell you exactly where it is facing the exception. :-)

Comment: @user2607115 try the edited post. it should work if not check the server side from where you get the json. Try the edit as a seperate project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your parsing problem its already answered @

[How to call the JSON object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789971/how-to-call-the-json-object-in-android/17790160#17790160)

Its a string

```
String secondvalue = jb.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
try
{
   int value = Integer.parseInt("secondvalue");
   Log.i("Customer id",""+value);
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:

```
  String myjson = "["
                  +"["
                  +"{"
                  +  " \"0\": \"2\"," 
                  +  "\"CUSTOMER_ID\": \"2\"" 
                  +   "}"
                  +  "]"
                  + "]";
```

Parsing

```
  try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myjson);
        JSONArray ja= (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(0);
        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
        String firstvalue = jb.getString("0");
        String secondvalue = jb.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(secondvalue);
        Log.i("Customer id",""+value);
        Log.i("first value is",firstvalue);
        Log.i("second value is",secondvalue);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
     {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @user2607115 you are welcome and accept the previous answer also coz that also solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the String (say, some_string) you have given as input to the `new JSONArray(some_string)` can not be converted to a JSON Array because the string does not follow the required json array format. An example of a proper JSON Array string is given below

> [   {
>       "title":"title_1",
>       "name":"name_1"   },   {
>       "title":"title_2",
>       "name":"name_2"   } ]