# org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, exception

Hi i got a problem with Android JSON Parser in 2.3, all is ok in 4.0>.

I look other topic they are talking about encoding (server) or other stuff server side, but i tried to put "test" in all my JSON field an the problem still persist.

Here is my code :

```
URL url = new URL(c.getString(R.string.url_ws) + url_ws);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
request.write("&test=test");
request.flush();
request.close();


String line;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
String json = sb.toString().trim();
try {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d(Tools.TAG+"/debug JSONException", e.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Here is my exception

```
debug JSONException(4184): org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

i saw double space between "Value" and "of" so i guess the problem is a empty string but i dont get it.

thanks.

**EDIT**

it was a encode mistake in my JSON,

```
char a = json.substring(0, 1).charAt(0);
int ascii = (int)a;
Tools.myLog(">"+ascii+"<");
```

i found 65279 char

## SOLUTION

[Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

encoding UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792779/what-is-the-error-denotes-in-androidjson-error-parsing-data-org-json-jsonexcep/17793283#17793283. similar!. Post your json.

Comment: JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json); use this instead of JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: my JSON isn't an array :

{"bHasError":false,"sSessionId":"5e10be14c408732179aa4731899882fd","iMembreId":7510064,"iCurrentDate":1374565720 ....

Comment: you need to show the JSON response

Comment: Log the string before creating the JSONObject so you can see if it's a json string.

Comment: {

    "bHasError": false,
    "sSessionId": "5e10be14c408732179aa4731899882fd",
    "iMembreId": 7510064,
    "iCurrentDate": 1374565720,
    "iExpirationDate": 1374567520,
    "aData": {
        "aVentesEnCours": [

Comment: You can check the validity of the json string here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: if my JSON was invalid the 4.0 won't parse it, isn't it  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

instead try

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
   json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
}
```

Follow this method for getting json object:

```
 public JSONObject getJSONObjFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {      
            System.out.println("url:: "+url );
            System.out.println("params:: "+ params +" " +params.get(0) );
            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                is.close();

                json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
               // Log.e("JSON:: ", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String

            return jObj;

        }
```

Comment: i delete the \n but your trick with substring make an error : debug JSONException(4461): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 242 of

Comment: Nice very good site i found the mistake it was a space between [" "] in my JSON, i update my question.
TYVM !